# Jenkins: How to pass strings to the body of the email notifications

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Inside the **Execute Shell**, a *LIST=$(ls -1 dir_name/*rpm)* is done.  How can I pass the contents of *LIST* so that they're displayed in the ***Default Content*** or whatever is the body of the **Editable Email Notification**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [InjectEnv plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) with some settings like below:

[image]

In the Jenkins build step (or post step), you can use the $MY_LIST variable:

[image]

```
+ echo build-failure-analyzer.xml buildtriggerbadge.xml cloudbees-plugin-gateway.xml com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder.xml com.orctom.jenkins.plugin.globalpostscript.GlobalPostScript.xml com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig.xml config_project_creation.xml config.xml config.xml.old Connection Activity monitoring to slaves.log credentials.xml Download metadata.log envinject-plugin-configuration.xml envInject.xml Fingerprint cleanup.log hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.xml hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml hudson.plugins.copyartifact.TriggeredBuildSelector.xml hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.xml hudson.plugins.git.GitTool.xml hudson.plugins.groovy.Groovy.xml hudson.plugins.logfilesizechecker.LogfilesizecheckerWrapper.xml
```